# ASP.NET Core MVC app failing to apply Entity Framework Core Migration on MariaDB. Specified key was too long

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, mariadb

Edit: It turned out I was using a database that was a different version from the one I specified in my Startup.cs class ConfigureServices method. Updating the production database solved the problem.

--- Original question below ---

This migration works in the same type of database server during development but not in production

running '$ dotnet core ef database update' produces the following result:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (5ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE `AspNetRoles` (
          `Id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
          `Name` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL,
          `NormalizedName` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL,
          `ConcurrencyStamp` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL,
          CONSTRAINT `PK_AspNetRoles` PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
      );
Failed executing DbCommand (5ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE `AspNetRoles` (
    `Id` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
    `Name` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL,
    `NormalizedName` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL,
    `ConcurrencyStamp` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `PK_AspNetRoles` PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
);
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
 ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
   at MySqlConnector.Core.ResultSet.ReadResultSetHeaderAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\ResultSet.cs:line 49
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet() in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line 130
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.CreateAsync(CommandListPosition commandListPosition, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, IDictionary`2 cachedProcedures, IMySqlCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlDataReader.cs:line 391
   at MySqlConnector.Core.CommandExecutor.ExecuteReaderAsync(IReadOnlyList`1 commands, ICommandPayloadCreator payloadCreator, CommandBehavior behavior, IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\CommandExecutor.cs:line 62
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(IOBehavior ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlCommand.cs:line 226
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() in C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\MySql.Data.MySqlClient\MySqlCommand.cs:line 74
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Migrations.Internal.MySqlMigrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I was using a database that was a different version from the one I specified in my Startup.cs class ConfigureServices method. Updating the production database solved the problem.